# Play framework ignores evolution script

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, playframework

I'm currently covering the basics of SQL databases and using them in play framework. I have created postgres database and successfully configured it in my application.conf

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://database.example.com/playdb"
db.default.user=postgres
db.default.password=qwerty
```

I have also created 1.sql file in conf/evolutions/evolutions/default directory and wrote there same example SQL code to create simple table. The problem is that play seems to ignore the existence of this file. When I run my server and connect to localhost, I'm suppoused to be asked by Play, whether I would like to have my script applied to my database or not. Unfortunately I'm not and the only thing play is doing, is loading my home page (CREATE TABLE in 1.sql is not executed and I don't have any tables created). Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @m-z I'm using 2.4.3

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask: Have you disabled evolutions? Check in `conf/application.conf` "evolutionplugin=disabled" should be commented out

Comment: Also, an off-topic hint: You may consider using something like: https://github.com/flyway/flyway-play

Comment: @Teolha Of course I haven't

Comment: Do you have the evolutions dependency in your `build.sbt`? `libraryDependencies += evolutions`

Comment: @m-z That was exactly the case! How could I miss it... Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have following line in your `build.sbt` file

```
libraryDependencies += evolutions
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, evolution ignored 2.sql (and 1.sql).

To resolve this I had to remove those comments from 1.sql:

```
#--- Created by Ebean DDL
# To stop Ebean DDL generation, remove this comment and start using Evolutions
```

and add my own comment such as:

```
# Initial version
```

Also, viewing 1.sql file in VI revealed it contains **^M characters which had to be removed**.

After those two steps, evolution stopped overwriting 1.sql and finally used the provided 2.sql file.

Evolution seems to overwrite 1.sql even if you do not perform the db update, so make sure you are editing the original version.

I am using play 2.4.1.